# Can't access CEX.io REST API

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get some cryptocurrency values from [CEX.io REST api](https://cex.io/rest-api#lprice) from a Google App script (to integrate with a google spreadsheet)

```
function myFunction() {
  var options = {
   'method' : 'get',
   'contentType': 'application/json',
   'escaping': false
 };

  var response = null;
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://cex.io/api/last_price/BTC/US", options);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

And the response I get is:

> {"error":"Invalid Symbols Pair"}

If I make this same request using postman or any other thing, it works as expected.
Does anyone knows if there is some kind of limitation from Google App Scripts or CEX.io REST API that doesn't allow me to make this request?
I can't find anything in the documentations ([here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) and [here](https://cex.io/rest-api#lprice))

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your url should be https://cex.io/api/last_price/BTC/USD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL consumption you made was hitting wrong machine. Use below URL instead,

GET https://cex.io/api/last_price/BTC/USD
Returns JSON example:

{ 
    "curr1": "BTC", 
    "curr2": "USD", 
    "lprice": "400.00" 
}